# Why is string pointer in golang behavior counter-intuitive in range-loop?

Tags: pointers, go

With this code: https://play.golang.org/p/tCm1W-K-6ob

This code would print: `[c c c]`, but `[a b c]` is excepted.

```
type A struct {
    a *string
}

func f() {
    slist := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    list := make([]*A, len(slist))
    for i, v := range slist {
        item := &A{
            a: &v,
        }
        list[i] = item
    }
    fmt.Printf("[%s %s %s]", *list[0].a, *list[1].a, *list[2].a)
}

func main() {
    f()
}
```

Why the list is not `["a", "b", "c"]`? What happened to the range or the `&string`?

Comment: Loop variables in Golang is actually shared for all iterations of the loop similar to JS, so `i` and `v` are the same variables for the whole loop. So you need to create a temp value for v if you want to get the address.

Answer (score 1):

https://play.golang.org/p/utJrUmxeqfh

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    foo := []int{1, 2, 3}
    for _, f := range foo {
        fmt.Printf("value is %d, addr is %p \n", f, &f)
    }
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

```
value is 1, addr is 0x414020 
value is 2, addr is 0x414020 
value is 3, addr is 0x414020 
Hello, playground
```

the value `f` in `range` has the same address

Comment: Expanded a bit further in https://play.golang.org/p/pLLVhRaJ0jo to match  OP's code more closely.

Answer (score 1):

The items all contain the address of the one local variable `v`.

If your goal is to assign the address of the slice element the `a` field, then do the following:

```
for i := range slist {
    item := &A{
        a: &slist[i],  // address of element instead of local variable.
    }
    list[i] = item
}
```

[Run it on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/svzrbtdVi1X).

You can also get the output you want by creating a new variable on each loop iteration:

```
for i, v := range slist {
    v := v  // create new value on each iteration.
    item := &A{
        a: &v,
    }
    list[i] = item
}
```

[Run it on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pEJOEIMW8_f).

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the iterator variable is allocated only once and the value it points to is changed with each iteration of the loop:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    a *string
}

func f() {
    slist := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    list := make([]*A, len(slist))

    // v is only allocated once and the value at it's address is changed
    // on each iteration.
    for i, v := range slist {
        fmt.Printf("Iteration %d: address of v %#v, value of v \"%s\"\n", i+1, &v, v)
        // Add in a temp variable, which will get allocated
        // and hence have a new address each iteration.
        t := v

        // Now assign that temp variable's address to the Item's a.
        list[i] = &A{
            a: &t,
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("[%s %s %s]", *list[0].a, *list[1].a, *list[2].a)
}

func main() {
    f()
}
```

**<kbd>[Run on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pLLVhRaJ0jo)</kbd>**

However, I have a strong feeling that this is unintuitive because we are pretty much talking of premature optimization. (A bit simplified): A string in Go is basically a slice of bytes(`[]byte`), with a slice already being a pointer to the backing array. See [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) for details.

Answer (score -2):

**You can try this**

Here I can run your code and do some changes.

https://play.golang.org/p/GmU3goeOKdF

here is code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    a  *string
}

func f() {
    slist := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    list := make([]*A, len(slist))
    for i, v := range slist {
        item := &A{
            a: &v,
        }
        list[i] = item

    fmt.Printf("%s", *list[i].a)
    }
}
func main() {
    f()
}
```

**Output** `abc`

Comment: You can see the answer..I think its helpful to you. @shougang

Comment: Link only answers do not help much. Should the link change or vanish, the answer becomes meaningless. Please include at least the gist in your answer.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg ,i am try to solve their question. so that i can only run code and do the some changes.

Comment: I understand that. But for the sake of long term knowledge retention, it makes sense to actually answer the question here completely, with links only adding information. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers for an in depth discussion why link-only anwers should be avoided.